# pthread_create in constructor segfault

Tags: c++, constructor, pthreads

I discovered, in this little example below, if I call pthread_create in the constructor of my struct, I get a segfault randomly on the call to pthread_mutex_lock().

And sometimes the name field is empty for the first philosopher.

If I move pthread_create to a run() function after the constructor, no segfault.

It seems the call to pthread_create happens before all the members are initialized.  Shouldn't the member init list of the class be completed before the call to constructor body?

Thanks for any tips!

clang version 9.0.0 (tags/RELEASE_900/final)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin17.7.0

Sincerely, George

```
#include <array>
#include <iostream>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;


struct chopstick
{
        pthread_mutex_t mutex;
        chopstick()
        {
                pthread_mutex_init(&mutex,nullptr);
        }
        ~chopstick()
        {
                pthread_mutex_destroy(&mutex);
        }

};

void* feed(void* data);
struct philosopher
{
        pthread_t thread;
        string name;
        unsigned mouthfuls;
        chrono::seconds sec;
        chopstick &left, &right;

        pthread_t& get_thread() { return thread; }

        philosopher(const string &s, chopstick &l, chopstick &r): name(move(s)), left(l), right(r), mouthfuls(0)
        /*
                enable below to avoid segfault
        {}
        void run()  
        */
        {
                pthread_create(&thread, nullptr, feed, this);
        };

};

void* feed(void* data)
{
        philosopher & a = *static_cast<philosopher*>(data);
        while (a.mouthfuls < 20)
        {
                pthread_mutex_lock(&a.left.mutex);
                pthread_mutex_lock(&a.right.mutex);
                cout << "Apostle " << a.name << " thread id " << pthread_self() 
                        << " acquired a chopstick at count: " << a.mouthfuls << endl;
                ++a.mouthfuls;
                pthread_mutex_unlock(&a.right.mutex);
                pthread_mutex_unlock(&a.left.mutex);
        }
        return nullptr;
}

int main (int argc, char const * argv[])
{
        array<string, 12> names {"John", "Thaddeus", "Simon Peter", "James", "Judhas", "Bartholomew", "Matthew", "Philip", "Simon Zealot", "Thomas", "Andrew", "James the Lesser" };
        array<chopstick,names.size()> sticks;
        vector<philosopher> philosophers;

        for (int i=0; i+1<names.size(); ++i)
                philosophers.emplace_back( names[i],sticks[i],sticks[i+1] );
        philosophers.emplace_back(names[names.size()-1], sticks[0],sticks[names.size()-1]);
        //for (philosopher&  a: philosophers) a.run();  //<-- enable to avoid segfault
        for (philosopher&  a: philosophers) pthread_join(a.get_thread(), nullptr);

        return 0;

}
```

Comment: Your `main()` is not accounting for the `vector` reallocating its array and moving elements around in memory. And your `philosopher` class is not following the [Rule of 3/5/0](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three) to allow those moves to be done safely. You should `reserve()` the `vector` since you know how many elements you are going to create in it

Comment: Unrelated: Which C++ version are you using? If you use C++11 or later you can use [`std::thread`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread) which has a portable C++ interface while `pthread` has a C interface that isn't in the C++ standard.

Comment: @TedLyngmo `<array>` comes from C++11 standard.

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin Indeed - then there shouldn't be any reason to use `pthread` directly (for new code). Even C11 (not C++11) has a portable [thread](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/thread) API that would be preferable over using `pthread` directly.

Comment: @Remy Lebeau et al

Excellent gentlemen.  Thank you so much for enlightening me.  I should have known.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`std::vector` resizes when the code does `philosophers.emplace_back()`, which can move the elements in memory, so that their previous addresses become invalid and the `feed()` function ends up accessing objects using their old invalid addresses.

A fix would be to make the `philosopher` class non-copyable and non-movable, and then use `std::list<philosopher>` or `std::forward_list<philosopher>` instead of `std::vector<philosopher>`. `std::list` and `std::forward_list` do not move elements in memory and hence are capable of storing non-copyable and non-moveable objects.

You may also like to use `std::thread` instead of `pthread_t`, and `std::mutex` instead of `pthread_mutex_t`. The `std` classes are non-copyable/movable which would prevent you from making this error at compile-time. Also, the code doesn't check return values of the pthread functions for errors, whereas `std::thread` and `std::mutex` do that for you.